# Spruce Budworm bifurcation diagram

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, parametric

The ODE that appears in the [Spruce Budworm Population](https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math55/DEproj/sp12/huang/paper.pdf) problem is the following:
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=r_PN\left(1-\frac{N}{K}\right) -p(N) \quad \quad \mbox{where} \quad \quad p(N)=\frac{BN^2}{A^2+N^2}$$ where $A$, $B$ are constants.
After some variable changes (you can check them on pages $4$ and $5$ of the document liked above) we get to the following ODE
$$\frac{du}{dτ} = ru \left(1 −\frac{u}{q}\right)−\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}$$
The bifurcation diagram, where we plot the parametric curves $r=\frac{2u^3}{(1+u^2)^2}$, $q=\frac{2u^3}{u^2-1}$ is [this one](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/waz33x9z). I want to know how can I find the coordinates of the point $A$ in the graph linked. I already know their values but I want to know a method to manually find their values. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cusp is only possible when neither $r$ nor $q$ provides a local coordinates, i.e., $r'(u)=q'(u)=0$.  You just have to solve it and get $u=0,\pm\sqrt3$ and you must go back and chck indeed that is a cusp, not a problem of silly parametrization like $y=x=t^2$ at $t=0$.